# Wordpress Loop and $post

Tags: wp-query, loop, core, globals

I decided to take a closer look at how WP works and ran into this question. I see that when WP is loaded, the wp() function is triggered, which will parse the request and get data from the database in the global $post variable, there will already be data. At the same time, WP recommends always using Loop, which will send the same request to the database again. I do not quite understand what is the point in this case of WP Loop. Which for example on the page/post just do the same thing?